# Jquery multi-countdown .each() function

Tags: jquery, countdown, each

I'm trying to make a multi-countdown on a page, which looks like :

```
<table>  
  <tr id="4236377487">
    <td class="remain"></td>
    <td>Something</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="768769080">
    <td class="remain"></td>
    <td>Something else</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Countdown must be placed in :

```
<td class="remain"><!-- countdown --></td>
```

Each countdown starts with the row id value. Here's my code, but it doesn't work :

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
  $('.remain').each(function () {
     var count = $(this).attr("id");
     countdown = setInterval(function(){
     $(this).html(count + " seconds remaining!");
     if (count == 0) {
       //do something
     }
     count--; 
     }, 1000);
  });  
});
```

Thank for your help :)

Fabien

Comment: var count = $(this).attr("id"); is looking at the .remain not the parent tr id.

Comment: I think you have  a bad design overall. Even if you fetch the proper id using parent, you would still be updating based on it's value and the timer would actually never decrease since id is always constant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
  $('tr[id]').each(function () {
     var $this = $(this);
     var count = parseInt($this.attr("id"));
     countdown = setInterval(function(){
         $('.remain', $this).html(count + " seconds remaining!");
         if (count-- == 0) {
           //do something
           clearInterval(countdown);
         }
     }, 1000);
  });  
});
```

Try it here : http://jsfiddle.net/moeishaa/PwG45/